# Character animation in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to create an animation which involves some characters dropping from top of the screen to the bottom. Something like leaves which are falling from trees. This animation should have these features:

1. I want to be able to choose the font and size of these characters (something like textblock)
2. I want them to tilt a little when they're moving (like leaves do)
3. I don't want too many of them but I want the performance to be satisfactory

Is this possible in XAML? I don't have much experience in complex animation in XAML so I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible, but it would be nice if you tried it yourself and came back with any specific questions. Not many people are willing to write complex code in Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm not looking for the whole answer. As I said, I don't have much experience and I just want some directions. Of course I wanna learn. I'm not posting my homework here!

Comment: Honestly, it's all going to look very scripted if you use the native storyboard features of XAML.

Comment: If you have access to Expression Blend, you can just try this all your self and animate visually, with timelines, etc.

Comment: From the next time any one down voting please add a comment and a reason. Try help others if you know some thing.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/) has an application called [BabySmash](http://www.hanselman.com/babysmash/download.htm) that contain a similar animation you can look for the source code in CodePlex or google it

Comment: I up voted just because the person who down voted did not leave a response or a reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a control that might be doing exactly what you need in the WinRT XAML Toolkit called [CascadingTextBlock](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/CascadingTextBlock.xaml.cs). Download the complete solution to see a sample.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link to story boards and animation go through it.

[Story board](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx)

try out applying story boards and animate the margin or the height width. I am not sure of the titlted effect but obviously you can make a search.